# Best Practice to load page on tap of back or close : In swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, back

I have a pure dynamic page page1VC (which is parent) where i have few buttons which takes them to page2VC, page3VC, page4VC

There is next button and back button in every view controller (no back button in p1VC as this is parent)

I can navigate to any viewController from any other vc i.e, from p1VC -> p2VC -> p4VC -> p3Vc

on tap of back in any view controller, that takes me to p1VC

page1VC gets all info to display from API and stores in variable p1APIInfo

On tap of back button from page2VC or page3VC or page4VC --> this should take me to page1VC

My question is:
As my page1VC is pure dynamic, on 1st landing of this page, i get all info from API 
When I navigate to page4VC and on tap of back it should take me to page1VC and here i dont want API to be called anytime when user taps back button

As of now i have a dummy variable in page1VC which is copy of p1APIInfo variable (say dummyAPIInfo)

Each time when i tap next im passing that variable to another VC, and on tap of back from that VC im passing back that variable. So basically this variable is to only transport data to other VC and get it back to page1VC on tap of "back" button. Im not using any data in this dummy variable in page2VC/page3VC/page4VC

However this works, but this is not best practice.

I can think of saving my page1 data in userdefaults/singleton but im looking for more optimizing solution

pls suggest how to handle

So to summarize: I want my API call to happen only once i.e., during 1st time landing..after that whenever user visits/tap back button from some other page, i need a way not to call API. It should use same data that user gets during 1st API call.

Hope I'm clear with my question. Pls advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do the calls in a function that isn't called multiple times. For instance, if your api calls are in the `viewWillAppear` method, you'll do a fetch every time you pop your navigation stack. Putting the api calls in `viewDidLoad` will ensure that your api calls only happen once.

As for a way to transport data back to page1...

- You could create a custom model that page1 relies on, and inject that model to other pages
- You could use the delegation pattern to pass back information
- You could use notifications and observers to broadcast and catch updates
- You could pass a reference of page1 to any other page and allow other pages to make updates to page1 on its behalf

All 4 strategies are viable, and really depends on your use case and what other things you need in your app. You could even use a singleton. `UserDefaults` seems like a bad idea though, since your use case is to update a model for a view controller.